# Receiving "(1)" error message using Xcode SVN comparison editor

Tags: ios, xcode, svn, version-control

I have set up Xcode (8.1) with an SVN server repository, and everything works fine except for this:

When I use the comparison version editor for some files I receive this error message, and it does not load a previous revision.

[image: Xcode (1) error message]

This does not happen when going into blame mode or log mode, in the version editor. They work perfectly.

Restarting Xcode fixes this for some files but not others?

Comment: Have you aver found a solution to this - I have the same problem... even for Xcode 9.1